# How can i print a listbox list in c# windows form app?

Tags: c#, forms, listbox, windows-forms-designer

I'm currently having issues with my code in terms of getting a printing option to show up when thy click a specific  button.

I am making a reminder program and was just experimenting. Also would like to know the most efficient way to add a daily notification system to my program

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
namespace simpleapp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add("Reminder: " + textBox1.Text);


        }
        private void input_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyData == Keys.Enter)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add("Reminder: " + textBox1.Text  );
            }

        } 

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int rmd = listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count - 1; rmd >= 0; rmd--)
            {
                listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(listBox1.SelectedIndices[rmd]);

            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

        }

        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FAQ faqs = new FAQ();
            faqs.Show();

        }

        // When the Button is Clicked the List is saved in a ".txt file format for the user to view later 
        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var Savingfileas = new SaveFileDialog();
            Savingfileas.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt ";
            if (Savingfileas.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                using (var Reminder = new StreamWriter(Savingfileas.FileName, false))
                    foreach (var item in listBox1.Items)
                        Reminder.Write(item.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
                MessageBox.Show("File has been successfully saved"+ '\n' + "Thank you for using the Remindr program");
            }
        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Email_Client emc = new Email_Client();
            emc.Show();



        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options. One is to graphically layout a print document and iterate through your listbox while drawing the text in the textbox using x and y coordinates. A better way would be to get your listbox items into a dataset and use it to generate a report. Are you storing these items in a database for retrieval? [Here's a link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/374426-printing-data-using-local-reports/) that should help you get started. The tutorial is in VB.Net but there's only a small amount of code to this and should be easy to repeat using C# code.

Comment: there no db cos im not sure how to conect it to db but i really want to learn how to do that :)

Comment: Hi, it's a standard in StackOverflow to include the contents or highlights of an external link that answers the question. If that page ever breaks your answer is useless and people have to dig through another resource they are not even sure addresses the issue. Please consider making a [edit], cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is an absolutely minimal example of printing a `ListBox`.

It assumes your `ListBox` contains strings and shows a `PrintPreviewDialog`; it sets the page unit to `mm`, do pick a unit you are comfortable with..!

Of course you may chose one or more different fonts etc..

```
    private PrintDocument document =   new PrintDocument();

    private void printButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog ppd = new PrintPreviewDialog();
        ppd.Document = document;
        ppd.Document.DocumentName = "TESTING";
        document.PrintPage += document_PrintPage;
        ppd.ShowDialog();
    }

    void document_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Millimeter;
        int leading = 5;
        int leftMargin = 25;
        int topMargin = 10;

        // a few simple formatting options..
        StringFormat FmtRight = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Far};
        StringFormat FmtLeft = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near};
        StringFormat FmtCenter = new StringFormat() { Alignment = StringAlignment.Near};

        StringFormat fmt = FmtRight;

        using (Font font = new Font( "Arial Narrow", 12f))
        {
        SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString("_|", Font);
        float h = sz.Height + leading;

        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(listBox1.Items[i].ToString(), font , Brushes.Black, 
                                  leftMargin, topMargin + h * i, fmt);
        }
    }
```

The actual printing is triggered when the user clicks the printer symbol in the dialog.

Note that there are  more  [`StringFormat`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) options!